# svn update is not working

Tags: svn, netbeans, svn-update

I am using netbeans IDE and svn repository to run my project .
I have updated the netbeans TO 7.3 version and checked out the repository again.

The code was successfully checked out.

But when I run the command   `svn up /var/www/` then the following error appears on command prompt :

> svn: The path '/var/www' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
>   working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
>   working copy.

I have browsed the error but unable to get any solution.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your command-line svn is 1.6 or older but you checked out your project with a 1.7 client.

What's the output of `svn --version` ?

Comment: command line svn is svn 1.6.17 version. Then what to do with it? Please help me.

Comment: @Sam how did you check out your project? Did you use `svn checkout` or did you use any svn plugin inside Netbeans?

Comment: I checkedout the code by using CHECKOUT option in netbeans interface . and I don't find any svn plug in netbeans

Comment: @Sam So I think Netbeans is using some embedded svn client which is not the same you invoke at command-line. I suggest either updating the svn command line to 1.7 or checking out the code again, but using the command line tool, and then importing the project into Netbeans (sorry, I use eclipse so I don't know how it's done in Netbeans)